# Аутентификация в веб сервисе

Tags: база-данных, apache, веб-сервер, 1с, веб-служба

Я установил сервер Apache 2.4 и создал веб сервис согласно [Создание веб сервиса 1C](https://xn----1-bedvffifm4g.xn--p1ai/news/2018-12-03-how-to-create-web-services-using-extensions/).

При открытии файла Customers.1cws на localhost получил следующее сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где в системе можно посмотреть пользователь и пароль для Apache (пользователь и пароль для Windows не подходят)?

Comment: По этому вопросу - легко нагуглить ! Примеров именно для Апача полно; для начала см: https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/5944/hdoc

Answer (score 0):

Если еще актуально то нужно писать логин пароль от 1с